# Xhtml namespace on https site?

Tags: url, ssl, https, xhtml

Im migrating a site from using `http` to redirect all requests to `https` and therefor im making sure external script, images etc are references with just // in the beginning of the url instead of `http://`

My question is this. Do i also need to change stuff like the `xhtml` namespaces for the html tag or the doctype declaration url? And if I do need to change this, will they resolve urls starting with //?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces are identifying strings that happen to use URL syntax. They should not be changed.

The DTD is a tricky one.

In **theory**, if it was altered with a man-in-the-middle attack, then it could be used to change named entities and insert new content into the document.

In practise however, browsers don't generally parse the DTD so this isn't *really* a worry. Additionally, [W3C DTDs are not served over HTTPS](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd) so you can't reference them without copying the files to your own server (and possibly updating internal references). If you want to be *really* safe, you should do this.

Personally, I'd scrap DTDs and just use (X)HTML 5.